# pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor doesn't return True when parameters should return True

Tags: python, colors, pyautogui

I want to be notified when certain parts of my screen turns white because that indicates that the page has completed loading and I can carry on. During debugging I realised that pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor doesn't return True when satisfying its parameters.

My original code:

```
import time
import pyautogui

def wait_until_white_detected_here(x, y):
    has_screen_loaded = 0
    while has_screen_loaded == 0:
        if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (255, 255, 255)) == True:
            has_screen_loaded += 1
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)

wait_until_white_detected_here(845, 129)
```

Further testing indicates that pyautogui.pixelMatch is reading from the correct `(x, y)` coordinates.

The part of the screen I was testing was actually white (i.e. RGB = 255, 255, 255). So I moved the screen to a purely white background (also RGB white) so that the `(x, y)` coordinates don't matter. But still it wasn't returning `True`.

My test code:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(845, 129, (255, 255, 255)) == True:
    print("found")
else: print("Not found")
continue
```

Is it my code screwing up because of an error on my part, or is it just `pyautogui`? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, and still nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try the `tolerance` parameter of the `pixelMatchesColor` function?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late response, but for some reason this issue was limited to my MacBook, probably because it is a Retina model. This is apparently a known issue. Even though it showed up as `(255, 255, 255)` on my PC, it wasn't actually that on my Macbook. Solved by running `im.getpixel((x, y))` on my Macbook instead.